# Angular Retain Proper Scroll Position when Transitioning Routes or Refreshing

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using `ui-router`.

A similar question has been asked on this a *Number* of times... But the solutions seem to be all over the place and either the question doesn't address a simple idea or the answer doesn't, either.

Here's my simple `ui-view` setup:

- A master view has the navbar and footer
- Children of the master view/route that can be activated include the Homepage, About Us page and Learn More page

Pretty simple...

By default, if the homepage is activated, and scrolled down 500px, and I click on a route to the "About Us" page, that page will be scrolled down 500px.  Obviously this is not desired.

So... Everyone's solution is some variation of setting `document.scrollTop(0)` on every state change success.  This is atrocious.

While it fixes the issue at hand, it clobbers the browser back button behavior. Here are some problems:

- When a refresh is called, the standard browser behavior of refreshing to the current location is ruined
- When the back button is clicked, the homepage would then scroll all the way to the top
- If the back and forward button were clicked, I wouldn't retain the correct spot on the next page, either

This whole `document.scrollTop(0)` or any variation of it, really doesn't seem to be viable and I've yet to see a clear solution to this.